# Loading .net wrapper fails to load native dependency

Tags: c#, wrapper, .net-assembly

Situation: multiple versions of a .net wrapper class, all named the same with same signature.  We want to dynamically load 1 of the wrappers in a wcf service method.  I plan to setup folders with each wrapper + dependant dll.  We'll use switch or if statements per user choice of version to run.

I've got Assembly.LoadFrom with path and can create an instance of the wrapper class. But calling a method in the wrapper fails with "cannot load or find CTV.dll".

If I change the machine or user Environment path to point to the CTV.dll, it will execute the method.  But this is global and will only point to a specific CTV.dll in one version folder.  I have tried many times

Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", [path to ctv.dll in the folder], EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);

But is has no effect, the same error occurs.

Is there something I am missing. It seems there would be an answer to this.

Is there another way to handle this use case?

Comment: To clarify for others. The dependent dll I needed to load was a native dll, not managed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution 1:

At first glance, loading the target native dll yourself before loading the managed wrapper seems to be a good solution (By using a [LoadLibrary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibrarya) call with an absolute path)

```
[DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError=true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string lpFileName);
```

From [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibrarya):

> If the string specifies a full path, the function searches only that
>   path for the module.

I want to talk about an alternative also, which I tried with success.

### Solution 2:

We can inject a new path into the search order of LoadLibrary by using the SetDllDirectory native API.

The native libraries are loaded using [LoadLibrary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibrarya) function and there is a certain [directory search order](https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order) for the libraries to be loaded.

See this section taken from the documentation of LoadLibrary function:

> The search path can be altered using the SetDllDirectory function.
>   This solution is recommended instead of using SetCurrentDirectory or
>   hard-coding the full path to the DLL.

I added a symbolic interop call to a non-existent module:

```
[DllImport("oguzozgul.dll")]
static extern uint InvokeOguzOzgul(IntPtr oguz, uint ozgul);
```

Then called this function and monitored the search behavior with [ProcMon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon)

[image]

You can clearly see in what order LoadLibrary looks for the native image. (On my system)

And then, before any calls to this non-existent module, I invoked [SetDllDirectory]:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool SetDllDirectory(string lpPathName);

// Calling SetDllDirectory:
SetDllDirectory("c:\\temp\\");
```

And called the method again. The result is as follows.

Right after checking the process' folder, LoadLibrary checks the injected path.

So if you call SetDllDirectory and add the correct directory path to the search order of LoadLibrary, the desired version of the native dll should be loaded from there automatically when demanded by the managed wrapper.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: Oguz, thank you very much for taking the time to explain this to me. I implemented approach 2 and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a dotnet-only solution (which does not involve native method calls) use an `AssemblyLoadContext`.

Here is my general-purpose `ResolvingAssemblyLoadContext` class:

```
using SysLoader = System.Runtime.Loader;
using SysReflect = System.Reflection;

public sealed class ResolvingAssemblyLoadContext : SysLoader.AssemblyLoadContext
{
    readonly SysLoader.AssemblyDependencyResolver resolver;

    public ResolvingAssemblyLoadContext( string assemblyFilePath )
    {
        resolver = new SysLoader.AssemblyDependencyResolver( assemblyFilePath );
    }

    protected override SysReflect.Assembly? Load( SysReflect.AssemblyName assemblyName )
    {
        string? assemblyPath = resolver.ResolveAssemblyToPath( assemblyName );
        if( assemblyPath != null )
            return LoadFromAssemblyPath( assemblyPath );
        return null;
    }

    protected override nint LoadUnmanagedDll( string unmanagedDllName )
    {
        string? libraryPath = resolver.ResolveUnmanagedDllToPath( unmanagedDllName );
        if( libraryPath != null )
            return LoadUnmanagedDllFromPath( libraryPath );
        return 0;
    }
}
```

It is general-purpose in the sense that it does not contain anything specific to my stuff, so it can be used as-is to cover any scenario where you need to load an assembly ***the right way***, so that the assembly will be able to find its native dependencies.

Of course, you can customize it to suit your own needs, for example to locate a specific DLL among all those different versions that you have.

Use it as follows:

```
SysLoader.AssemblyLoadContext assemblyLoadContext = new ResolvingAssemblyLoadContext( assemblyFilePath );
SysReflect.Assembly assembly = assemblyLoadContext.LoadFromAssemblyPath( assemblyFilePath );
```