# C# Unable to load DLL 'SDL2'

Tags: c#, sdl

I've been searching the internet all over for 2 hours trying to fix this issue but every time I try to execute the code, it will start then about a second later it crashes with this error.

> Unable to load DLL 'SDL2': The specified module could not be found.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

I am completely dead on ideas. I've tried putting the .dll in references, in the main project folder, as a .cs file + "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy if new". I've tried setting the project to x64 and x86.

Used: https://github.com/flibitijibibo/SDL2-CS also used it from NuGet.

Someone please help me.

Using Windows 10.

```cs
SDL.SDL_Init(SDL.SDL_INIT_AUDIO); // Crashes on this line

SDL.SDL_WindowFlags flags = 0;
if (resizable)
    flags = SDL.SDL_WindowFlags.SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE;

var window = IntPtr.Zero;
window = SDL.SDL_CreateWindow(
    windowTitle,
    windowX,
    windowY,
    windowWidth,
    windowHeight,
    flags
);

SDL.SDL_Delay(3000);
SDL.SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
SDL.SDL_Quit();
```

Comment: `I am completely dead on ideas` - grab [procmon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) and see exactly what is being not found exactly where.

Comment: It is probably the path list "LoadLibrary" function uses to locate the native library the SDL managed library is utilizing. procmon will help you diagnose where the runtime looks for the sdl library.  You can see this post with two suggestions as solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61281867/loading-net-wrapper-fails-to-load-native-dependency/61282761#61282761

Comment: check out https://github.com/awaescher/Fusion a fusion log (fusion is the dll resolve engine thingy) viewer.